# Number selection algorithm (to fill up total amount)

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to create an algorithm in SQL(syntax doesn't really matter) that will read the results table that consists of 2 columns:
number (1,4,15,30...etc) and it's quantity(1,2,3,4,5...) like:

```
number qty
3     5
7     3
15    2
30    9
```

and then creates a resultset based on how many of these numbers can fit within a certain *value*, maximum number of numbers(sorry for tautology) should be used, but numbers should be used in such way that they are utilize *value* most efficiently (leaving least amount of leftover space).

Sample for value = 87

```
number    qty
3         5   (87-15 = 72 leftover)
7         3   (51 leftover)
15        2   (21 leftover) - not efficient 

number    qty
3         5   (72 leftover)
7         3   (51 leftover)
15        1   (36 leftover)
30        1   (6 leftover) - better but probably not the best
```

Comment: I think we're going to need a clearer description of the task.  "A resultset based on..." doesn't tell me what the desired output is; it tells me that the output has to depend on those things, but not how it should depend on them.   I don't know what "maximum number of numbers should be used" means.  What constitutes "most efficiently"?  What's the definition of "leftover space"?  I think there's a lot going on in that sentence.  Can you break it down into multiple sentences, and introduce a variable for each quantity and use mathematics to make it clearer what the desired output is?

Comment: An example is not a substitute for a clear, general specification of the task you're trying to solve.  We can advise you on an algorithm, but how to implement in any particular language (e.g., SQL) is likely out-of-scope here.